# How to give parameter lang to another url

Tags: javascript, php, html, gettext

I use GetText library to have a multilingual website. It works great on my first page with this url `http://localhost:8080/index.php?lang=en_US`

But inside my page, I have link to another page. I'd like to keep lang=en_US to send to the second page to have this dynamically according to the selected language:

```
<a href="contact.php?lang=en_US">text here</a>
```

I don't know how to do it, if I have to create the url with appending string by getting parameter the first time and concatenate it? or session ?

Comment: Try to see with .htaccess and make url like domain.com/en/
and when you go deeper 
domain.com/en/your_page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to change your links to something like this:

```
<a href="contact.php?lang=<?=$_GET['lang']?>">text here</a>
```

Comment: **Danger**: This code is [vulnerable to XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS) User input needs escaping before being inserted into an HTML document!.